# Setting up static IP for virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, arp

I was learning [arpspoofing](https://docs.oseems.com/general/operatingsystem/linux/sniff-network-traffic).I was using my Ubuntu machine as the [Man in the middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack), an Ubuntu in my virtualbox as the target and my default gateway(Which is `10.7.1.2`) as the target gateway. In order to sniff the traffic between two machines the machines must be in the same network. When I checked `route -n` on my virtualbox host it showed that it uses the gateway address `10.0.2.2` which is different from the one I use for my host machine.

Is it possible to bring the virtualbox to my network and assign any static IP like `10.7.1.x`?

Comment: Is your VM network interface set to Bridged?

Comment: @user5069652 What is bridging. I am fairly new to this. Sorry

Comment: In the machine's config check: `Network -> Adapter -> Attached to: "Bridged Adapter"`

Comment: @ripat I found that now. Could you please explain the remaining steps as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the VB guest configuration for the Ubuntu, change the network adapter 1 type from NAT to Bridged Adapter.

Then start Ubuntu guest and change as root (or sudo) the `/etc/network/interfaces` to setup a static interface:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.7.1.7
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.7.1.2
```

And make sure to remove or comment out any stanza mentioning dhcp. Restart your network with `sudo service networking restart` or restart your guest.

If you need domain name resolution on the Ubuntu guest, you will also have to add a DNS in the `/etc/resolv.conf`. For example

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```